# Python: Getting WinError 997 , while using mouse clicks in pyautogui package

Tags: python, mouseclick-event, pyautogui

here is the code

```
    import serial;
    import struct;
    import pyautogui;
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False;
    i=0;
    sig=[0.1];
    ser=serial.Serial('COM8',9600,);
    ser.flush();
    Lclick=0;
    while (1):
        sig[0]=(struct.unpack("<f",ser.read(4))[0]);
        #print ('\n');
        if (sig[0]>2.2) and Lclick==0:
            pyautogui.mouseDown();
            Lclick=1;
        elif (sig[0]<1.9 and Lclick==1):
            Lclick=0;
            pyautogui.mouseUp();
    ser.close();
```

I am reading flex sensor voltage from COM8 bluetooth serial port. When I execute this code, its making one Down click and after that it is showing the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/sem4/embd/Project/Mclick.py", line 27, in <module>
    pyautogui.mouseUp();
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 315, in mouseUp
    platformModule._mouseUp(x, y, 'left')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 415, in _mouseUp
    _sendMouseEvent(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 480, in _sendMouseEvent
    raise ctypes.WinError()
OSError: [WinError 997] Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.
```

surprisingly, when the print state is uncommented,the code is working fine. I could control mouse clicks. I don't understand how it is doing that and why its giving error when the print statement is commented. Can some one help me?

Comment: `Clock (cpu) / process_time = your_click_count ` Don't make crazy your mouse-down function !  Define an event before calling somethings(if changed, available, delay).